# How to create a findAllByUser query where user is a member an embedded class?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I have the next two domain classes in a grails application:

```
class Room {
    String name
    RoomType roomType
    def static findAllByUser = { user, params ->
        List<Room> rooms = Room.findAll("from Room r where r.roomType.user = :user", [user: user], params)
        return rooms
    }
}

class RoomType {
    String name
    User user
}
```

I wan to be able to retrieve all the rooms created by a particular user.

```
def currentUser  = currentUser()
def rooms = Room.findAllByUser(currentUser)
```

In order to achieve that I implemented the clousure *findAllByUser* in the Room domain class.

However, when I invoke the closure i get a Null Pointer exception in this line.

```
List<Room> rooms = Room.findAll("from Room r where r.roomType.user = :user", [user: user], params)
```

The user is not null. So It must be my poor HQL. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a better bet would be to use a named query. It's nicer looking and can provide more functionality too:

Just add this to your Room domain class

```
static namedQueries = { 
    byUser { findUser ->
        roomType {
            eq 'user', findUser
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
def roomsByUser = Room.byUser(currentUser).list()
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

1) set default behaviour to 2nd parameter 'params' if u don't use it!

```
class Room {
String name
RoomType roomType
def static findAllByUser = { user, params = [sort:'name'] ->
    List<Room> rooms = Room.findAll("from Room r where r.roomType.user = :user", [user: user], params)
    return rooms
}
```

}

2) rename 'currentUser' variable to 'user' for example (i suppose that closure name is similar to variable name => not good)

```
def user = currentUser()
def rooms = Room.findAllByUser(user)
```

But more elegant solution is to put query logic into the grails service (e.g. RoomService.groovy)

Comment: Do you really need to create rooms variable? Maybe that's enough:
def static findAllByUser = { user, params = [sort:'name'] ->
    Room.findAll("from Room r where r.roomType.user = :user", [user: user], params)
    }